# One of my pools disapears after reboot

Tags: zfs

One of my pools disappears after reboot. I have Debian Buster Root on ZFS and my bpool and rpool pools are OK.

```
root@ZFSTEST:~# zpool status mkpool
  pool: mkpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 0 days 00:22:38 with 0 errors on Sun Oct 11 00:46:39 2020
config:

    NAME                                           STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    mkpool                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST1500DL003-9VT16L_5YD0ZB9G            ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST31000524AS_6VPH8BWP                  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-001CA0_WD-WMAYU3034792  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
root@ZFSTEST:~# reboot
####SYSTEM REBOOT
root@ZFSTEST:~# zpool  status mkpool
cannot open 'mkpool': no such pool
root@ZFSTEST:~# zpool import mkpool
root@ZFSTEST:~# zpool status mkpool
  pool: mkpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 0 days 00:22:38 with 0 errors on Sun Oct 11 00:46:39 2020
config:

    NAME                                           STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    mkpool                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST1500DL003-9VT16L_5YD0ZB9G            ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST31000524AS_6VPH8BWP                  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-001CA0_WD-WMAYU3034792  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Can anyone help?